# Does installing fglrx driver changes xorg.conf (custom resolutions)?

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, fglrx

I use an LCD with 1920x1080 resolution and VGA connection. When I first installed Ubuntu it showed only up to 1360x768 in display settings. I added 1920x1080 resolution by using `gft/cvt` commands and editing `xorg conf` after reading a blog. It fixed and I use Ubuntu 1920x1080 now. Now I want to install `fglrx-updates` hoping it will produce better    performance on 3d apps/games.

Q1: Is there a big difference between standard driver of ubuntu for ati cards and additional fglrx (performance-wise)
Q2: Does installing overwrites xorg conf (drivers didn't find my 1920 1080 native res last time)
Q3: How do you uninstall fglrx drivers from terminal in case sth goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Yes, fglrx has much better 3d performance. Some people report worse 2d performance, though.

Q2: Installation itself does not edit xorg.conf. I recommend to make a backup anyhow. If you run aticonfig --initial, what might be necessary to configure fglrx after installation, it will back up the current xorg.conf and install a new one.

Q3: Simply apt-get purge fglrx-updates. Then copy back the backed up xorg.conf in case it was replaced.

Comment: Thanks. I decided I don't need ati drivers since I don't use 3d apps that much.

Comment: Be aware that nearly all modern desktop environments can use 3D acceleration and a few (including Unity and Gnome 3) do not work well without. So, if your desktop is slow or stuttering, using a driver with better 3D performance will very probably help. If you want to have a fast desktop without 3D acceleration, I recommend to use a window manager that does not use or allows to disable compositing.

Comment: I use cinnamon, it is good-looking and fast. Ati drivers bypass xorg.conf and does what they please I think, btw.